# integrating the statistical distribution to get the total number of electrons

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I am looking at the following formula and trying to understand why the following integration of the electron energy $E_e$ is the total number of electrons:

$\int d^3pf(E_e,T) = N_{e} V$

where $N_e$ is the electron energy density and V is the volume. Therefore $N_{e} V$ is the just the total number of electrons.

I integrate the following:

$\int p^2 dp \frac{1}{\exp(p/T)+1} = \frac{3}{2}T^3\zeta(3)$

I see that $V=T^3$ so this integration provides a $V$ but I don't know here the $N_e$ comes from.

Comment: Hint: What does $f$ represent physically? Also double check your units

Comment: so $f(E_{i},T)=1/(\exp(E_i)/T+1)$ is the average number of fermions in a single-particle state $i$. So I suppose by integrating over the momentum $d^3p$ this the average number of fermions (for a fixed temperature) over all momentum space.